# Angular accessing scope attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the below code as a directive.  I'm trying to pass `scope` from a controller to this directive, and it seems to be passing it properly (`console.log(scope);` works fine).  However when I try to access the `scope.data` attribute, which looks like it should return an array in the `console.log` for `scope`, it returns `undefined`.  Why is this and how can I fix this?

```
myApp.directive('d3Cloud', ['$window', 
                            'd3Service', 
                            'd3Cloud', 
                            function($window, 
                                     d3Service, 
                                     d3Cloud) {
  return {

    // Restrict usage to element/attribute
    restrict: 'EA',

    // Manage scope properties
    scope: {

      // Bi-directional data binding
      data: '=',

      // Bind to DOM attribute
      label: '@'
    },

    // Link to DOM
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      // Load d3 service
      d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {

        // Create svg variable
        var svg = d3.select(element[0])
          .append('svg')
          .style('width', '100%')
          .append('g');

        // Re-render on window resize
        window.onresize = function() {
          scope.$apply();
        };

        // Call render function on window resize
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return angular.element($window)[0].innerWidth;
        }, function() {

          // Works fine!
          console.log(scope);

          // Returns undefined!
          console.log(scope.data)

          scope.render(scope.data);
        });
        ...
```

**Added HTML:**

```
  <div class="inner-module" ng-controller="DownloadsCloudCtrl">
    <div class="module-graph">
       <d3-cloud data="d3Data"></d3-cloud>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### Important Edit:

The problem has been getting weirder.  I just refreshed the page, and it grabbed the data perfectly.  Refreshed again and received `undefined` again.  I'm going to try to change the variable name from data to something else.

EDIT #2:

Tried changing the variable name and it doesn't seem to recognize any parameter other than `data`... weird...

Comment: what does your html look like for your data=

Comment: added HTML to the question

Comment: try renaming your data variable. I know angular does stuff behind the scenes with data- maybe its doing something finicky. Also is d3Data being populated in the controller?

Comment: Yes `d3Data` is definitely being populated in the controller.

Comment: Should it be `<d3-cloud data-ng-model="d3Data"></d3-cloud>` and `console.log(scope.d3Data)`?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

The directive was loading before the `http` service had finished loading the data.

### Solution:

Add an `ng-if` conditional to make sure the data has loaded before initiating the directive.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="module-graph" ng-if="dataLoaded">
  <d3-cloud data="d3Data"></d3-cloud>
</div>
```

**Within controller:**

```
requestService.getP2PKeywordData(month, year).then(function(data) {
  $scope.d3Data = data.data;
  $scope.dataLoaded = true;
});
```